# Create TreeView Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

My question is that , I want my output is shown in the **select tag**, in the form of
       **Dropdown list**(treeview Structure) and also i wanted to select multiple categories 
      with the help of Using html tag i.e, **Checkbox**.

```
<?php
function getCategory($parent_id){
    $con = connect_db();
    $sql = "select ocd.category_id,ocd.name, occ.parent_id from oc_category_description ocd, oc_category occ where ocd.category_id=occ.category_id and  parent_id='".$parent_id."' ORDER BY name";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {

        echo "<ul>";
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
          { 
           echo "<li>".$row->name.'('.$row->category_id.')'."</li>";
           getCategory($row->category_id);     
         }
        echo "</ul>";
      }
    }
$parent_id = 0;
getCategory($parent_id);
?>
```

Here the output:-
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npGbP.png])

Answer (score 0):

You can show your results in a Dropdown list with these lines of code.Hope this is what you wanted.

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {

```
    echo '<select name="nameUwanted">';
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
      { 
       echo "<option value='". $row->name ."'>" .$row->name.'('.$row->category_id.')'."</option>" ;
       getCategory($row->category_id);     
     }
    echo "</select>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not the correct answer .i want all the categories shown  in the  single select tag with is tree view structure.see this link  https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jqueryscript.net%2Fimages%2FMulti-Select-Dropdown-Tree-Plugin-Bootstrap-jQuery.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jqueryscript.net%2Ftags.php%3F%2Ftree%2520view%2F&docid=1BRIfedywH66ZM&tbnid=K6ZmFc7BbczvvM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjO1LDl747lAhVJcCsKHUd9BDMQMwhMKAIwAg..i&w=536&h=399&bih=669&biw=1299&q=tree%20view%20drop%20down%20list&ved=0ahUKEwjO1LDl747lAhVJcCsKHUd9BDMQMwhMKAIwAg&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: Refer this [demo](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/kM4Q) Tree view and customize the above code,Hope this will work as expected